# CONVERT not working for VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've tried everything I can find (`CAST`, `CONVERT`, converting on import, checking default language settings) but I cannot find a working solution to convert my `VARCHAR` values to `DATETIME`. I'd like to insert a conversion of this field into a new table where that column is set up as `DATETIME`.

When I run:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, [first air date], 121) 
FROM mytable
```

the results are returned fine and error free. However, when I run:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
    SELECT ID, column1, column2, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, [first air date], 121) 
    FROM mytable
```

I get this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

Why am I getting results (as in the first query) but it won't insert them into another table?

The data looks like this: '2004-02-23 00:00:00.000' (I know the dashes aren't best practice but I have no wiggle room on that because this format has been determined by other colleagues).

I'm importing the data via `.csv` and this column is set as date format in Excel.

**Correction**
I now realise it should be CONVERT(DATETIME, [first air date], 121). However, this does not solve the actual problem at hand, which is converting to DATETIME from VARCHAR without the 'out of range' error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, always include the length of a varchar for a conversion.  Second, you really want to convert to `DATETIME`, which is the destination type.

Third, you can get the non-convertible values using:

```
SELECT [first air date]
FROM mytable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, [first air date], 121) IS NULL
```

You can then figure out how to handle the values that cannot be converted.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for that quick answer! However, when I ran this suggested query it is returning only the rows that are NULL. Should there not be NULL values? Why does it work when I run the SELECT statement (just shows the NULLs as NULLs) but not when I attempt to INSERT the converted data?

Comment: Are those values `NULL`, the SQL value or `'NULL'` a string?

Comment: Actual NULL, not a string

Comment: @CShrad . . . See the revised answer.  You need to convert to a `DATETIME` rather than `VARCHAR()`.  The problem is an out-of-range error, so you should readily be able to spot the issues.

Comment: The revised answer makes perfect sense and when I run the SELECT statement as SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [first air date], 121) 
FROM mytable, I now get the out of range error (which is consistent as would be expected). Unfortunately, it's this error which necessitated this post in the first place. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since the column has a format that can be sorted in a useful manner, just select the top 5 rows and order by [first air date] in both ascending and descending order. The error message is clear - there are values that exceed the lower/upper boundary of the datetime datatype.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, using what you recommended I deepened my investigation and found that some of the 'dates' were entries like '8456-93-12' so couldn't be converted. Thank you for helping me find these anomalies.